# Change maxHttpHeaderSize for only a single request

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

How can you change Tomcat's maxHttpHeaderSize for only a single request?  I do not want to change it for the entire connector.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question -

```
((ServletServerHttpResponse)outputMessage).getServletResponse().setBufferSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```